# Upgrade MVC2 to MVC3 - Problem only on Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have upgrade my MVC2 project to MVC3 using this tool: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2011/01/13/mvc-3-project-upgrade-tool.aspx

Which is working fine and my Project is also runnig fine on my local pc, but when i deploy it to the server, which is also has MVC3 installed, it just return this error:

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\a8d37933\32de45bd\assembly\dl3\b1e279bf\0dc3e090_ffd7cb01\BaseUtility.DLL: error CS1705: Assembly 'BaseUtility, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mvc\2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Mvc.dll: (Location of symbol related to previous error)
```

And my webconfig also contain this part:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>


<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Anyone have a idea how do i fix this problem,
Thanks in advance
Jack

Comment: Is MVC3 defn installed on your server?  Or in the bin folder of your web app?

Comment: MVC3 is installed on the server. I have uploaded a test MVC3 website also and the test web-site is working.

Comment: I have solved the problem now. I have checked my webconfig file and found out that a part of it is still using MVC2 in the <assemblies/>

Comment: You should go ahead and put this as an answer and mark it so.  This is what solved my issue as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Hambonious, This solved my problem:

I have checked my webconfig file and found out that a part of it is still using MVC2 in the .