# Orchard1.6 doesn't build visualstudio 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, orchardcms

I just download the new version of Orchard1.6 and build that in VisualStudio 2010 but I cannot build, it gives the following error:

> Assembly 'Orchard.Web, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher
>   version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

If you have a solution for this problem, please share it.

Comment: try looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117889/assembly-someassembly-uses-system-web-mvc-version-4-0-0-0-which-has-a-highe and related questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the source code if you want to compile from VS. Also please avoid cross-posting.